# How to pass parameter in SubReport from Main Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports, parameter-passing

I've a stored procedure that runs my main report.

```
            HPR rpt = new HPR();
            rpt.SetDataSource(objdt.fetch("EXECUTE sp_hpr @DATE ='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00") + "'", objdt.strconnection));
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

The above query gets me the relevant details.

Now, I want to display just one row in main report footer, first I add another select query in my stored procedure but it didn't worked then someone told me to use `SubReport`, which I did but I really don't know:

1. How to execute the second stored procedure for subreport which also
   requires DateTimePicker?
2. How do I pass the value of DateTimePicker in my subreport?

every time I run my program a dialog appears and ask me to enter the parameter value ! and after that another appears for my login credentials.

please help !

Comment: If the answer is relevant to your Question then mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it,

```
            HPR rpt = new HPR();  // Crystal Report Object
            rpt.SetDataSource(objdt.fetch("EXECUTE sp_hpr @DATE ='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00") + "'", objdt.strconnection));

            //This is how you run your sub report in main report while passing @date parameter in stored procedure. "rptSub" is your sub report name !

            rpt.Subreports["rptSub"].SetDataSource(objdt.fetch("EXECUTE sp_hpr_avg @DATE ='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00") + "'", objdt.strconnection));

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Follow these steps to pass the parameters from main report to sub report**

1. Create a new paramter @mainParam in the main report by right-clicking on 'Parameter Fields' section in Field explorer in the main report.
2. Create a new parameter @subParam in the sub report in the same manner (This wouldn't be required if  you already have the parameter in the sub report)
3. Right click on the sub report in the desing window in your main report.
   You will be able to see an option 'Change Subreport Links'.
4. Click on the option and select the @mainParam and transfer it to the sub report using '>' button.
5. Select the appropriate field in the sub report to map to
6. Click ok.